# UISplitViewController split vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

Is it possible to make the split in UISplitViewController vertical instead of horizontal split?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do that with a UISplitViewController. If you want to do that, you can make your own split-view-like controller by adding two container views to a view controller in IB, and size them how you like. You will have to implement your own methods for hiding the master controller if you want to do that.